# Best approach to make an online dictionary?

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, frameworks

I'm trying to create an online dictionary (some rare languages) and need you suggestions.
My php, mysql and javascript knowledge though is far from excellent, but is enough to understand the code and make some changes to it. I've done some projects with Drupal before and now thinking about trying a php framework for this project, because I belive that php framework could be more flexible in this case. I don't have any experience with any frameworks. The project isn't commercial, more like a hobby.

So, the question is - Is it worth trying a php framework or should I stick with Drupal? Maybe, some other options?

Thank you.

Comment: should your question be best php framework/cms?

Answer (score 2):

Some people thinks that writing your own engine instead of using a CMS is not worth.
But if you use a framework, such as Zend Framework, Symfony, CakePHP, CodeIgniter, etc... you will be able to have a robust basic engine which could be extended to your needs, and get improved with time.
With time, you write your own library which you know, and, the most important, which fits to your specific needs.

So, try to find the tool before to write it, but write it you was not able to find it, or it was not adapted to your needs, or adapting it will you cost you extra times.

Think of the following things :

- Is the template engine will let me able to design anything I want
- Is the software enough modular to let me able to develop plugins or new modules
- Is it worth to learn how to use it ?
- Is it activly developed, and documentation is available ?
- Will it cost me extra time to develop with it instead of writing it from the scratch and create my own library ?
- And probably others things i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention PHP, why not consider Mediawiki (the engine behind Wikipedia) ?

Comment: And after that, which extension to use?

Answer (score 0):

There's always [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/), if it's an open project that you're working on.

Comment: I think it's off topic.